# How to play an audio mp3 file in appery

Tags: audio, ionic-framework, playback, audio-player, appery.io

I need to play an audio file in Appery ionic app when user clicks the play button.
I have tried this >>
https://blog.appery.io/2015/10/how-to-play-a-custom-sound-in-your-mobile-app/

But it is not working. I tried to play audio from URL and local file. Both are not working

Comment: can you build a codepen and show what you have done. Others can check what part is not working

Comment: what say  your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @k185 and @Antonis.There is a plugin that could be used "Cordova Media Plugin". Check this >>https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

This worked for me :)